# javascript error in if condition. "Unexpected token &&"

Tags: javascript

In a javascript i am storing an array of values. My question I want to compare each and every index value. When I am using && I am getting error saying

[image]

[image: The string message in alert]

```
var result =<value>;
if(result["compiled"] !=  "false") && (result["success"] != "false"))
  alert("successfully");
else
  alert("Please check you Debug log for the error");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a parentheses at the start of your `if` condition.

```
if(result["compiled"] != "false") && (result["success"] != "false"))
```

Should be:

```
if((result["compiled"] != "false") && (result["success"] != "false"))
```

Or you can omit some brackets:

```
if(result["compiled"] != "false" && result["success"] != "false")
```